# having trouble with autolayout -- simple calculator app

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

I'm new to autolayout and is having trouble arranging UIButtons and UILabels in a simple calculator app.

Here is [Github page](https://github.com/dzjustinli2/CalculatorSelf) that contain my current calculator app.

1) I cant make the "0" so that it is vertically aligned with "1", "4", "7"

2) I want to make the border of UIButton and UILabel 1px black. I can't find settings that can change border color and border width of UIButton in Storyboard inspectors.

3) How do I make "calculateStepsLabel" and "resultLabel" transparent so that whatever is in the background can be partially seen.

[image: My Calculator][image: Calculator app]

Comment: Please post your layout xml

Comment: We need to see your constraints. To get the border I would probably just have  a black background and set the button size/spacing so that there was a hairline gap, exposing the background color.  You can easily set the background color of a lable using the color inspector, but the Apple calculator you have shown has used an effect view to blur the background as well

Comment: Thank you both for helping out! I have included a link to the github page that contain my current calculator app. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Select the 0 button. In the IB inspector, right under line break, you'll see "Edge". Change it to title. Set the value of the left one to "-90". Try it. Adjust as needed. Either that, OR make the bottom row 4 buttons. disable the one after the 0 and before the decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would suggest going with the alternative that @Brandon mentioned. Since you're using stack view, you would not be able to give different spacing between two elements in same stack.
2. Use following code for label:

`resultLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor 
resultLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0`

Similarly for button:

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
```

3. Select Label -> go to attributes inspector -> View -> background. Click on background and adjust opacity to 50% or as desired to make background transparent. Here you can also select whatever color you want in background.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem for part 1 of the this question. Since stack view is pretty inflexible in terms of solving this problem, is there any alternatives you would suggest?

Comment: You can use UIButton there with proper constraints.